# IF statement to calculate days between dates if column contains date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two columns, Last Upload and Final Date. I have a formula to calculate the difference between today and the Last Upload using

```
=DATEDIF( [@[Last Upload]],TODAY(),"d")
```

However, sometimes the Last Upload column will be blank and in this case we would like to use the Final Date column instead.

Is there a way to combine and use the above statement when the column is not blank and the other when it is? I have been trying to nest it with an IF statement but struggling to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
=DATEDIF(IF(LEN([@[Last Upload]]),[@[Last Upload]],[@[Final Date]]),TODAY(),"d")
```

`LEN` might be a little bit more error-proof than `ISBLANK`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ISBLANK` formula combined with `IF` formula.

```
=DATEDIF(IF(ISBLANK([@[Last Upload]]),[@[Final Date Upload]],[@[Last Upload]]),TODAY(),"d")
```

Comment: I seem to be getting #VALUE! when I try entering the formula

Comment: Try to see what is the return value of =ISBLANK([@[Last Upload]]).

Comment: Interesting... It is returning FALSE even when there is no value in the Last Upload column. When I click inside the formula for the cell and click out, it sets it to TRUE